# How to add a line of text and save using Command Prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

im looking ways add a line into a text file using CMD.

> the below is the original files.

```
{"jobStorePath":"JobStore","spoolerId":"68f8b4d1-e9c2-40ca-93bd-b10e9c233f7f","uiId":"68f8b4d1-e9c2-40ca-93bd-b10e9c233f7f-ClientUI","defaultPaperSize":"A4"}
```

and i would like to add 
"updateLocations": "false" in to the line.

> Result

```
{"jobStorePath":"JobStore","spoolerId":"68f8b4d1-e9c2-40ca-93bd-b10e9c233f7f","uiId":"68f8b4d1-e9c2-40ca-93bd-b10e9c233f7f-ClientUI","defaultPaperSize":"A4","updateLocations": "false"}
```

Comment: isn't that `add` and `update` operation?

Comment: You can use the nano text editor if you are on OSX or Linux.
[Here](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v3/nano.html) is the link

Comment: I'm assuming that by CMD, you are referring to the windows command line.

Answer (score 0):

Use a python script to do the job that you can call from the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys
import json

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print('invalid input arguments.')
    print('python3 insert_update_locations_false.py [file_name]')
    exit()

file_name = sys.argv[1]

def main():
    print_job = read_file_in()
    print_job['updateLocations'] = False
    rewrite_file(print_job)


def read_file_in():
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        jsonObj = json.load(f)
        return jsonObj


def rewrite_file(jsonObj):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(jsonObj, f)


main()
```

Then you can call it from the command line as follows:

```
python3 insert_update_locations_false.py job1.txt
```